# FFMPEG mix mp4 and wav but add a delay to the start of the mp4

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am mixing an MP4 file with a WAV file. The MP4 contains both audio and video. Basically the mp4 is a video of someone singing to a beat. The WAV file contains the beat.

In the resultant file the WAV file is slightly behind the MP4 file. If possible I don't want to trim the WAV file at the start in order to bring it forward, I would much rather add a delay to the MP4 (both audio and video in the MP4) so that the resultant file is all sync'd up. I cannot do any manual steps as I am doing this programatically from within an app.

Here is my current command, it mixes the MP4 and the WAV and uses a filter to manipulate the volume levels

```
-i /home/video/file.mp4 -i /home/music/beat.wav -preset veryfast -crf 32 -filter_complex [0:a:0]volume=0.5[fa];[1:a:0]volume=0.5[fb];[fa][fb]amix=inputs=2:duration=first[fc] -map [fc] -map 0:v:0 -c:v copy -shortest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an offset to the MP4. Use aresample to plug the gap in the audio due to the offset. The video will appear frozen for *offset* amount of time at the start.

`-itsoffset 0.5 -i /home/video/file.mp4 -i /home/music/beat.wav -filter_complex "[0:a:0]aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,volume=0.5[fa];[1:a:0]volume=0.5[fb];[fa][fb]amix=inputs=2:duration=first[fc]" -map [fc] -map 0:v:0 -preset veryfast -crf 32 -c:v copy -shortest`

Comment: This command runs successfully however adding the itsoffset argument doesnt help to synchronize the mp4 with the wav. the playback is the same. the only thing i noticed that is different is when I played the resultant video back, my video player seekbar was on 'offset' seconds. For example if i do 'itsofset 2', then the video playing software seekbar is on the 2 second mark when the file opens, but when it plays it seems exactly the same as when the itsoffset parameter isnt included in the command

Comment: Which player? ..

Comment: Both the Ubuntu stock video player and VLC in ubuntu.

Comment: In case you could take a look at my source files here is the mp4 and the wav compressed into a zip file https://we.tl/t-TnEnPQJtEn

Comment: Edited cmd.....

Comment: your edited command does appear to add the offset in! thank you very much for your assistance